# Artin 2nd Ed. Problem 12.5.3

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, ideals, factoring

The problem says "Find the generator for the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ generated by $3 + 4i$ and $4 + 7i$."

I don't understand the question.  It asks us to find the generator of the ideal, but then it tells us what the ideal is generated by.

Here is an attempted solution using the tip from kjo:

We are looking for the GCD of $3 + 4i$ and $4 + 7i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

We will find it using a Guassian version of the Euclidean Algorithm.

$||3 + 4i|| = 25$ and $||4 + 7i|| = 65$

The GCD of these norms is 5.  Any common divisor of our numbers $3 + 4i$ and $4 + 7i$ must divide $5$.

$5 = (2 + i)(2 - i)$

Calculate: $\frac{3 + 4i}{2 + i} = \frac{(3 + 4i)(2 - i)}{(2 + i)(2 - i)} = \frac{10 + 5i}{5} = 2 + i$

So $2 + i$ divides $3 + 4i$.

Calculate: $\frac{4 + 7i}{2 + i} = \frac{(4 + 7i)(2 - i)}{(2 + i)(2 - i)} = \frac{15 + 10i}{5} = 3 + 2i$

So $2 + i$ is the GCD of $3 + 4i$ and $4 + 7i$ so it is the generator for the ideal.

EDIT: I think I got it.  I made some silly mistakes on my solution before.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: every ideal is principal. so you have to find the single generator.

Comment: Analogously, in $\Bbb Z$, what is the generator of the ideal $\langle 16,40\rangle$?

Comment: As a follow-up to Ted Shifrin's comment, you may find [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/82376/13675) useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Eliminate to get the coef of $\,i\,$ to be $= 1\!:\ $ $ 2(3\!+\!4i)-(4\!+\!7i) = 2+i =:\alpha \in I.\,$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\alpha\mid \alpha\alpha' = \color{#0a0}5,\ \ {\rm so}\ \ {\rm mod}\,\ 2\!+\!i\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{i\equiv -2} &\,\Rightarrow\,& 3\!+\!4\color{#c00}i\equiv 3\!+\!4(\color{#c00}{-2})\equiv\ \ \ {-}\color{#0a0}5\ \equiv\  0\\
&\Rightarrow& 4\!+\!7\color{#c00}i\equiv 4\!+\!7(\color{#c00}{-2})\equiv -2(\color{#0a0}5)\equiv 0
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\ \ $$

Therefore $\ I = (i+2)\ $ (why?). $ $  Alternatively, apply the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: I attempted a solution of the problem using the Euclidean algorithm and I got a different answer.  Could you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Nevermind.  I made a silly mistake.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great! The Euclidean algorithm is the best way to proceed in general. For special small problems, other ways might be faster (and more elementary), e.g. as above.