# Prove there are infinitely many primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I saw a proof online there are infinitely many primes in $\mathbb{Z}$.  The Euler product let's us factor the harmonic series:

$$ \prod  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) = \sum \frac{1}{n}$$

I wonder if this extends to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  Joan Baez [Week 216](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week216.html) of This Week's Finds defines the zeta function of number field as <del>the sum over non-zero ideals</del> basically:

$$ \zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(s) = \sum \frac{1}{(m^2 + n^2)^s} = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{Z}[i]} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{|p|^s} \right) $$

Here $2 = (1+i)(1-i)$ means that $2$ is ramified in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  When does this converge?

$$ \sum_{m, n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(m^2 + n^2)^s} \approx \frac{\pi}{4}\int \frac{ dr }{r^{2s-1}} < \infty$$

This zeta function converges for $s > 1$ since we are adding more numbers. So for $s = 1$

$$ \zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(1) = \sum \frac{1}{m^2 + n^2} = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{Z}[i]} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{|p|} \right) = \infty $$

We should also check that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has unique factorization, because it has a Euclidean algorithm

---

**Did we just prove $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has infinitely many primes?**

If that doesn't work, we show that $\zeta(2)$ is irrational.  In fact $\zeta_{\mathbb{Z}}(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but what about $\zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(2) $ ?

- [Different ways to prove there are infinitely many primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/different-ways-to-prove-there-are-infinitely-many-primes)
- [GCD of gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/gcd-of-gaussian-integers)

Comment: A much simpler way to prove there are infinitely many primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is to prove that in $\mathbb{Z}$ there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k + 3$ and infinitely many primes of the form $4k + 1$; the former are also prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the latter correspond to the norms of Gaussian primes with nonzero imaginary parts.

Comment: Another way is to use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600449) question and that $\Bbb Z \subset O_K$ is integral for any number field $K$ (and that $\Bbb Z$ has infinitely many prime ideals, and that $O_{\Bbb Q(i)} = \Bbb Z[i]$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your proof does indeed work (with a few minor corrections to your definition of $\zeta_{\mathbb Z[i]}$), and whilst it is not the easiest way to prove that $\mathbb Z[i]$ has infinitely many primes (see the other answer), the proof works in a much more general setting:

> **Theorem:** Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers. Then $\mathcal O_K$ has infinitely many prime ideals.

The proof is exactly the same as the proof in your question. Define the *Dedekind zeta function*
$$\zeta_K(s) = \sum_{0\ne\mathfrak a \subset \mathcal O_K}N\mathfrak a^{-s},$$where $s\in \mathbb C$, the summation is over non-zero ideals of $\mathcal O_K$, and the *norm* of an ideal is defined by $$N\mathfrak a = \#\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak a.$$

Equivalently, $$\zeta_K(s) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nn^{-s}$$
where $a_n=\#\{\mathfrak a \subset\mathcal O_K:N\mathfrak a =n\}$. When $K=\mathbb Q$ this is just the Riemann zeta function. When $K = \mathbb Q(i)$ as in your question, then we will have $a_n = 0$ whenever $n$ cannot be written as a sum of two squares. However, for example, when $(x+yi)$ and $(x-yi)$ are different ideals, we will have $a_{x^2+y^2}\ge2$, so this function is slightly different to your $\zeta_{\mathbb Z[i]}$.

This series converges absolutely in the half-plane $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$ and has a simple pole at $s=1$.

Now $\mathcal O_K$ may not be a UFD. However, it will always be a *Dedekind domain*, so it will be the case that every *ideal* can be uniquely factorised as a product of *prime ideals*. It follows that we can write
$$\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\mathfrak p\subset\mathcal O_K}(1-N\mathfrak p^{-s})^{-1}$$where the product is over prime ideals, converges absolutely for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$ and has a simple pole at $s=1$. Your proof now applies.

---

Even further generalisation is possible. For example, by considering the *Dirichlet characters*$$\chi:(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times\to\mathbb C^\times$$and their corresponding *L-functions*
$$L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi(n)n^{-s}=\prod_p(1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-1}$$(and some amount of hard work), one can prove *Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions*: that for any $a$ with $(a,m) = 1$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ with $p\equiv a \pmod m$.

One can go even further, and consider what an analogue of this theorem would be for a general number field. One quickly finds oneself playing with some of the ideas of *Class Field Theory*. For a good introduction to this approach, see (especially chapter 2 of) [Class Field Theory by N. Childress](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387724898).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Modify slightly the argument of   [Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid.27s_proof) by taking $q= 4 p_1\cdot \ldots \cdot p_n-1$ to show that $q$ has a prime factor $\equiv -1 \mod 4$ which is also different from all the $p_i$'s. Therefore, there exist infinitely many prime numbers of form $4 k-1$. These will also be prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ ( see [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer))

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Prove there are infinitely many primes in $Z[i]$"

You may also use Gauss reciprocity/quadratic reciprocity to classify all prime ideals $I$ in  $A:=\mathbb{Z}[i]$: The prime ideals in $A$ are the following ideals:

$I:=(p)A$ with $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ an odd prime and $p \cong 2,3(mod(4))$.

$I:=(a+ib)$ with $(a,b)=1$ and $a^2+b^2=p$, with $p$ an odd prime and $p \cong 1(mod(4))$.

$I:=(1+i)$.

Any odd prime $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ is $\cong 1(mod(4))$ or $\cong 2,3(mod(4))$ and there are infinitely many primes $p$, hence $A$ has infinitley many prime ideals.

[Rings of integers and extension of primes: When does a prime remain prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607630/rings-of-integers-and-extension-of-primes-when-does-a-prime-remain-prime)