# How do we prove the "lying over" property for integral extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R \subset S$ be an integral extension of commutative rings.  Then if $P \subset R$ is prime, there exists a prime ideal $Q \subset S$ such that $Q \cap R = P$.

My D&F book says look at Corollary 50, but I cannot find it in the book!

Is the proof easy or does it require much build-up lemmas?

Hints, or location of Corollary 50, please.

Comment: Let $Q$ be the pullback to $S$ of a maximal ideal of $(R - P)^{-1} S$.

Comment: Page 720 :)${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&pg=PA398&lpg=PA398&dq=proof+THE+LYING-OVER+THEOREM&source=bl&ots=cSM8knYaOj&sig=gGJFxL3svNEh6mORPxegRS3PHKE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipwOTXgpPKAhXFPBoKHWRWA_IQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=proof%20THE%20LYING-OVER%20THEOREM&f=false) is the proof: *Theorem 5.9 of the book "Algebra" by "Hungerford"*.
you can also find a proof in many books about Commutative Algebra; for example:

- 5.10 of the book *Introduction To Commutative Algebra* by *Atiyah Macdonald*
- 13.34 of the book *Steps in Commutative Algebra* by *Sharp*

Answer (score 0):

I can do some of the proof on my own maybe :)

Let $P \subset R$ be an ideal.  Then in particular $P$ is a subring of $R$ as well as $S$.

Let $Q = \{ s \in S : s \text{ is integral over  } P\}$.  Then it too is a subring of $S$ and in particular an additive subgroup and on its way to being an ideal.

Buy an earlier theorem, $Q = Pt_1 + \dots Pt_n$ must be a finitely generated $P$-module.  Then so to is $sQ$ for any $s \in S$, namely $Q = P(t_1 s) + \cdots + P(t_n s)$.  Thus $Q$ is an ideal of $S$.  Since $R \subset S$, the contraction of $Q$ to $R$, $Q \cap R$ is an ideal, being the inverse image of a hom that includes $R$ in $S$.

Notice that $Q \cap R \supset P$, thus there is a surjective hom $R/P \to R/(Q\cap R)$.  I don't know how to prove that $Q \cap R$ is also prime, maybe it's not!