# I need to compute $gcd(6+7i, -1+3i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to compute the $gcd(6+7i, -1+3i)$. I tried to calculate the function $\phi = (6 + 7i)(6-7i) = 85$ decomposed into prime factors is $85 = 5*17$,
 and $\phi = (-1+3i)(-1-3i) = 10$ decomposed into prime factors is $2*5$. But now I'm stuck. What can I do now?

Comment: What does the "cmmmdc" mean? What does "fi" mean? Is that supposed to be $\phi$?

Comment: For starters, you can try writing gcd instead of "cmmmdc" because the majority of the audience is likely not well versed in Romanian..Secondly, what is $i$ here?

Comment: What is cmmmdc?

Comment: cmmdc = greatest common factor

Comment: and 7i and 3i complex numbers...

Comment: fi(Z) = z*z(conjugated)

Comment: So what does "fi" mean???

Comment: Use the Euclidean Algorithm. Do **not** try to find prime factors.

Comment: This post will likely help you- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/gcd-of-gaussian-integers

Comment: I try solve this with euclidean algorithm but i can't find GCD can u help me?