# How to find the highest common factor of two complex numbers

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I have $$7+i,\quad\quad 5+3i\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$$

The answer is given as $$7+i=(5+3i)\cdot 1+(2-2i)$$

$$5+3i = (2-2i)\cdot 2i+(1-i)$$

$$2-2i=(1-i)\cdot 2$$

So $hcf(7+i,5+3i) = 1-i$

What I don't understand is how they're finding what to multiply by, like in the first line, they multiply $5+3i$ by $1$, in the second line they multiply $2-2i$ by $2i$. I tried using the fraction $\frac{7+i}{5+3i}$, and then rationalising the denominator but it got complicated and didn't look anything like what they've gotten. Could someone explain their steps in more detail?

Comment: Duplicate of [GCD of gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/gcd-of-gaussian-integers). Also see some of the links posted there: [Finding GCD of Complex Numbers with Euclidean Algorithm](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/67068.html), [GCD computations in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32157/gcd-computations-in-mathbbzi).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, those links solved my issues. Wasn't able to find it because I didn't know what gaussian integers were.

Comment: In an ideal world, those MSE links would have been automatically listed under the `related` column on the RHS of this page. But apparently the MSE search function doesn't know how to find $\mathbb{Z}[i]\,$, either.